# pip install Django

Tags: python, django, ssl

I'm trying to install Django on my Linux server. I've installed Python and pip successfully, but I'm getting the SSL error when I ran this pip install Django.

```
pip install Django
```

---

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting Django
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Django
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using python 3 or superior

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools ca-certificates
```

then use

```
pip3 install django
```

[python](/questions/tagged/python) [django](/questions/tagged/django)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the ssl module if you're using python2 python-openssl, python3-openssl for python3.
If that doesn't work try to upgrade the pip version.